# Set that is closed and bounded, but not compact?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness

**Let $\mathbb Q $ be the set of rational number with d(p,q) = |p-q| and E be the set of all  p $\in \mathbb Q$ such that $2 < p^2 < 3$.**

Intuitively, I think about closedness using subspace topology :

$\mathcal T_{\mathbb Q}$ = $\{\mathbb Q \cap (a,b): a,b \in \mathbb R \}$

so, E can be written as union of two closed sets $\{x\in \mathbb Q : \sqrt 2 < x < \sqrt 3 \}$
and $\{x\in \mathbb Q : -\sqrt 3 < x < -\sqrt 2 \}$ = $\{ \mathbb Q  \cap [-\sqrt 3, -\sqrt 2] \} \cup $ $\{ \mathbb Q  \cap [\sqrt 2, \sqrt 3] \}$

Also it is bounded, but we have a result any closed and bounded set in $\mathbb R^n$ is compact, this problem contradict with this result. I am confused, please help me

thank you

Comment: The set is _closed in_ $\mathbb{Q}$, but it is **not** closed in $\mathbb{R}$. Note that closedness is not an inherent property of a set, it is always closed **in** some ambient space (or not closed).

Comment: how to show that E is closed in $\mathbb Q$

Comment: $[a,b]\cap \mathbb{Q}$ is closed in $\mathbb{Q}$. If $a$ and $b$ are irrational, that is the same as $(a,b)\cap\mathbb{Q}$ (and hence also open).

Comment: why E is not compact in $\mathbb Q$

Comment: Compactness is an intrinsic property of a topological space, so the ambient space (if any) is irrelevant. The ambient space can allow simple characterisations of its compact subspaces, like $\mathbb{R}^n$ does, but still a space is compact or not, regardless of in which other space it is embedded. Anyway, $E$ is not compact because it is not complete. Every compact space is complete.

Comment: @ Daniel Fisher: Thank you for helping me

Answer (score 4):

The issue here is that you are discussing two different topologies: the topology on $\mathbb{R}$, and the topology on $\mathbb{Q}$ inherited as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}$.

In $\mathbb{R}$, the set you are considering is not closed: $\sqrt{3}$ is a limit point, but is not contained in it.  So, it is not a contradiction to say that this set is not compact in $\mathbb{R}$ -- because it is not closed in $\mathbb{R}$!

Comment: @ Nicholas:E is not complete in $\mathbb R$, because $\sqrt 2$ is a limit point of E , but not in E, so E is not complete in $\mathbb R$. What can u say about the completeness in $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: It isn't complete in $\mathbb{Q}$ either; for each $n$, let $a_n$ be $-\sqrt{2}$, rounded down to $n$ decimal places.  Then each $a_n\in E$, and the sequence $(a_n)$ is clearly Cauchy... but it doesn't converge.